# Not able to retrieve JWT access token from Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to retrieve a  JWT access token from Docusign but getting error in return as "no_valid_keys_or_signatures".

I have created the request as suggested on the developer portal (https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/#Create)
still getting error in return.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Ankit

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check (accept) the best answer for each of your questions. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**no_valid_keys_or_signatures**: This error covers several cases:

- There is an issue with the private key used to sign the assertion (for example, using a demo key in the production environment).
- The assertion is missing an `exp` (expiration) parameter
- The `aud` (audience) parameter is invalid - confirm the audience value is exactly account.docusign.com or account-d.docusign.com with no https:// prefix or trailing slash (/).
- An `nbf` (not valid before) parameter is defined, and that time has not been reached. The nbf parameter is optional and can be removed from the assertion, but if it is present, it must be a time in the past.

Source: [DocuSign Developer Support FAQs](https://support.docusign.com/articles/DocuSign-Developer-Support-FAQs)

**Also** Check that your computer's clock is set correctly, including the timezone. If the clock is wrong, the `nbf` claim will be wrong.